# Render controller in TWIG and show form errors

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have indexAction and contactAction

contactAction is a simple form with no mapped fields (FormType) like below:

```
/**
 * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
 * @Template()
 * @param Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $firstName = $form->get('first_name')->getData();
        $lastName = $form->get('last_name')->getData();
        $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
        $message = $form->get('message')->getData();
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

and i render this form in my indexAction with this TWIG command:

```
{{ render(controller('RusselBundle:Default:contact')) }}
```

Everything is okey, if page is not reloaded, HTML5 validators works fine, but if form have some errors like: firstName length, error's not show at all, how can i do, so that errors showed up in the form indexAction?  Any help would be appreciated. I'm just curious it's possible, and if - how ? Sorry for my english....

Comment: can you post the twig content?

Comment: where do you have your firstName length restriction defined? You should be using some entity that defines the validation rules to get them automatically checked by the isValid() function and consequently, errors automatically displayed in the form view

Comment: I've never used this syntax {{ render(controller... in a twig, try {{ form }} in place of {{ render(controller('RusselBundle:Default:contact')) }}. {{ form }} will generate all fields speficied by you ContactType, and will ensure the display of errors. If it works, after you'll be able to try other form function http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html which may be more useful for you needs.

Comment: @ejuhjav probably in the contacttype

Comment: could you post the ContactType content?

Comment: You should call {{ form_errors(form) }} in your twig template explicitly

Comment: @ejuhjav i have this in my ContactType:

        $builder
            ->add(
                'first_name',
                null,
                array(
                    'label' => 'Imię:',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'constraints' => new Length(array('min' => 3))
                )
            )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using the request passed into the action you should get the master request from the request stack. As @DebreczeniAndrás says, when you use the `render(controller())` you are using a newly created sub-request rather than the request that was actually passed to the page on load (the master request).

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thx !! this solve my issue ;) $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();

Answer (score 3):

On symfony3 use render function like this

```
{{ render(controller('RusselBundle:Default:contact', {'request':app.request})) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `render` function in your twig, then that creates a subrequest, thus your original posted (i.e. in your main request) values get lost.

You can pass your main request to your form render action as follows:

```
{{ render(controller('RusselBundle:Default:contact'), 'request' : app.request ) }}
```

This will pass all the main request parameters appropriately to your subrequest.